Given a n-dimensional polytope and a m-dimensional polytope, how could one compute the union, intersection, and difference?
A n-dimensional polytope consists of a shell (outer boundary) and arbitrarily many holes (inner boundary), with finitely many vertices. Given arbitrary polytopes (not necessarily the same dimension, and not necessarily convex), is there a known way to compute their union, intersection, or difference? If so, could you provide such an algorithm?
I'm also not really sure what a good way of representing n-dimensional polytopes would be; it seems like both the H-representation and the V-representation are only suitable for convex polytopes. Could you also suggest a reasonable way of representing it? I was thinking that it could be a union of simplices, but I'm not sure how tractable computing that would be.

ultimately it's going to be determined by the presentation of the $n,m$ polytopes*

Hence me asking for a reasonable presentation
